# How to read oracle not spatial data using pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, attribute-joins, oracle-spatial

I'm working on a QGIS plugin. I'm trying to join a vector layer and a non-spatial table both in Oracle spatial.

I add the vector layer to the map, but I can not add the table without geometry so i can join the layers. I have to pull it out and add in CSV format then I add it as CSV file, do I?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by specifying `None` in the geometric column:

```
uri.setDataSource('', 'TABLE',None,'','TABLE_ID')
```